# can we convert NSPointerArray to Array?

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, swift

I have a situation where I am going to use NSPointerArray , I want to filter the data stored in NSPointerArray as I can't use filter on NSPointerArray i want to convert it to Array.

How can I convert from NSPointerArray to array?

Answer (score 0):

You can get [`allObjects`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspointerarray/1408081-allobjects) from an `NSPointerArray` as an `[Any]`.